# Drupal 6: Make custom function available to different modules

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a couple of custom PHP functions that I would like to make available to several modules I created.

What would be the drupal-correct way to get around this problem? Basically, I would like to avoid copying all those functions inside every module I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can't just copy the functions into every module because if you have two or more modules with those functions then you'll get PHP errors about the function already having been declared (unless you go through the effort of renaming them in each module).

The best way to go about it depends on your exact usage, but assuming they are a collection of related core or api functionality, then I would place these into a separate module and then any additional modules could have the core module as a dependency.

Comment: To clarify: any function declared in your .module file will always be available to other modules. Doesn't matter if they are dependencies. Making the module that has the functions a dependency is a good idea or you can wrap the use of the function in an if(module_exists('module_with_function)){}

Comment: Thank you!
Alright, you are totally right about the multiple declaration issue.
I will put all those functions inside a new module and test it out. I suppose it would be a good idea to create a dependency between my custom-functions modules and all the other modules, right?